# How can I share something on Google+ from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-plus

I will make a sharing function in which the user can share something on Google+.

But the SDK for Google+ SignIn is deprecated and the new `GoogleSignIn` SDK seems to work only for sign in.

Does someone have experience on this?

**Reference links:**

**Sharing to Google+ from your iOS app:**
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/

**Migration from Google+ SignIn:**
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible** from the new SDK. Excerpt from [the site you've linked](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/):

> Native sharing on iOS requires that you use Google+ Sign-In, which is deprecated, and is likely to not function as expected. Do not use native sharing in new apps. You can use [basic sharing](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share) to share content on Google+ without Google+ Sign-In, and you can use [App Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/ios) to share deep links into your app with your users' contacts.

You should display an `SFSafariViewController` which points to `https://plus.google.com/share?url=<your URL>`.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://plus.google.com/share?url=<your URL>") {
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    present(safariVC, animated: true)
}
```